# How to display ServerSentEvents with Angular

Tags: angular, server-sent-events

I have a web service (Java backend) emitting *ServerSentEvents* (Reactor Flux).

I want to catch each event with an Angular client and display it in a table.

I can see incoming events, but they never are displayed. In fact, they seem to never reach the function responsible for displaying them.

The object I wanna display is of type '`ChronoWrapper`' and I've created a class for it :

```
export class ChronoWrapper {
  className : string;
  methodName : string;
  durationMillis : number;
  constructor(className : string, methodName : string, durationMillis : number) {
    this.className = className;
    this.methodName = methodName;
    this.durationMillis = durationMillis;
  }

  isNotEmpty() : boolean {
    return this.className != undefined && this.methodName != undefined && this.durationMillis != undefined;
  }
```

}

Here is the HTML for display :

```
<div>
  <p>dashboard-view works!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Class name</th>
      <th>Method name</th>
      <th>Duration in Milliseconds</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let event of serverSentEvents; index as i">
      <td>{{ i }}</td>
      <td>{{ event.className }}</td>
      <td>{{ event.methodName }}</td>
      <td>{{ event.durationMillis }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is the associated Typescript class :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CallSseService} from "../services/connection/call-sse.service";
import { ChronoWrapper } from "../model/chrono-wrapper";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard-view',
  templateUrl: './dashboard-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-view.component.css']
})
export class DashboardViewComponent implements OnInit {

  private _url : string = 'http://localhost:8080/chrono/transmission';
  serverSentEvents: ChronoWrapper[] = [];

  constructor(private _sseService : CallSseService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._sseService.getEvents(this._url)
      .subscribe((eventData : MessageEvent) => {
        console.log('Event type = ' + eventData.type);
        if (eventData.data.length > 0) {
          let clearedData : ChronoWrapper = JSON.parse(decodeURI(eventData.data));
          console.log('DATA = ' + clearedData);
          let chrono = new ChronoWrapper(clearedData.className,clearedData.methodName,clearedData.durationMillis);
          if (chrono.isNotEmpty()) {
            this.serverSentEvents.push(chrono);
          }
        } else {
          console.log('Nothing to display');
        }
      });
  }

}
```

Finally, here is the service in charge for listening events emitted by the server :

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CallSseService {

  constructor() {
  }

  _eventSource : EventSource | undefined;

  newEventSource(path: string): EventSource {
    let source = this._eventSource;
    if (source == null) {
      source = new EventSource(path);
      console.log('EventSource connected');
      this._eventSource = source;
    }
    return source;
  }

  getEvents(url : string) : Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return new Observable(event => {
      let eventSource = this.newEventSource(url);
      eventSource.addEventListener('Chrono', event => {
          console.log('Event received : ' + event);
          return event;
        },
        false);
      console.log('Listener up');
      return () => eventSource.close();
    })
  }

}
```

In the debug, I can see incoming events and their content :

```
id:148
event:Chrono
retry:1000
data:{"className":"TaskManagerImpl","methodName":"submitTask","durationMillis":"101"}
```

Is there anything I obviously don't see ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misconception about `Observables` a correct implementation should look like this :

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable,Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CallSseService {

  constructor() {
  }

  _eventSource : EventSource | undefined;
  _subject = new  Subject<MessageEvent>();

  newEventSource(path: string): EventSource {
    let source = this._eventSource;
    if (source == null) {
      source = new EventSource(path);
      console.log('EventSource connected');
      this._eventSource = source;
      this._eventSource.addEventListener('Chrono', event => {
          console.log('Event received : ' + event);
          this._subject.next(event.data);
        },
    }
    return source;
  }

  getEvents(url : string) : Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return this._subject.asObservable()
  }

}
```

Comment: While doing so, the object I get is no more a MessageEvent but an Event one. There's no way to get the content of the '.data' property.

Comment: @Lovegiver I can't know what kind of object you throw from the server-side. It's just a demo of how to push data into an observable from an `EventSource`.